# filter a pandas data frame on all rows that do NOT meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas

This seems simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I know how to filter a pandas data frame to all rows that meet a condition, but when I want the opposite, I keep getting weird errors.

Here is the example. (Context: a simple board game where pieces are on a grid and we're trying to give it a coordinate and return all adjacent pieces, but NOT the actual piece on that actual coordinate)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[5,7, 'wolf'],
              [5,6,'cow'],
              [8, 2, 'rabbit'],
              [5, 3, 'rabbit'],
              [3, 2, 'cow'],
              [7, 5, 'rabbit']],
              columns = ['lat', 'long', 'type'])

coords = [5,7] #the coordinate I'm testing, a wolf

view = df[((coords[0] - 1) <= df['lat']) & (df['lat'] <= (coords[0] + 1)) \
    & ((coords[1] - 1) <= df['long']) & (df['long'] <= (coords[1] + 1))]

view = view[not ((coords[0] == view['lat']) & (coords[1] == view['long'])) ] 

print(view)
```

I thought the `not` should just negate the boolean inside the parentheses that followed, but this doesn't seem to be how it works.

I want it to return the cow at 5,6 but NOT the wolf at 5,7 (because that's the current piece). Just to double check my logic, I did

```
me = view[(coords[0] == view['lat']) & (coords[1] == view['long'])] 
print(me)
```

and this returned just the wolf, as I'd expected. So why can't I just put a `not` in front of that and get everything else? Or, more importantly, what do I do instead to get everything else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As `numpy` (therefore `pandas`) use bitwise operators, you should replace `not` with `~`. This is also the reason you are using `&` and not `and`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})

print(df[~(df['a'] == 1)])
>>    a
   1  2
```

And using your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[5,7, 'wolf'],
              [5,6,'cow'],
              [8, 2, 'rabbit'],
              [5, 3, 'rabbit'],
              [3, 2, 'cow'],
              [7, 5, 'rabbit']],
              columns = ['lat', 'long', 'type'])

coords = [5,7] #the coordinate I'm testing, a wolf

view = df[((coords[0] - 1) <= df['lat']) & (df['lat'] <= (coords[0] + 1)) \
    & ((coords[1] - 1) <= df['long']) & (df['long'] <= (coords[1] + 1))]

view = view[~ ((coords[0] == view['lat']) & (coords[1] == view['long'])) ] 

print(view)
>>    lat  long type
   1    5     6  cow
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I had also tried using `!` because I thought something like that might be happening, but I was still a little off. Thanks again.

Comment: Using the .isin() method helps subset with a lot of items. `df = df[~(df['my column'].isin(['item1','item2']))]`